# Replace function and its derivatives found with Solve

Tags: equation-solving, replacement

If I have an equation

```
eq = f[x] + g[x] == 0
```

and I solve for `f[x]`

```
sol = Solve[eq,f[x]]
```

how do I use `sol` to replace both `f[x]` and its derivatives in another equation? For example

```
eq2 = f'[x]*g[x] + f[x] == 0
```

and then

```
eq2 /. sol
```

outputs

```
{-g[x] + g[x] f'[x] == 0}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is caused by the internal structure of `Derivative`:

```
f'[x] // FullForm

(* ==> Derivative[1][f][x]  *)
```

There's no `f[x]` in there to replace. Using `D[f[x], x]` instead of `f'[x]` and `Hold`ing the whole equation works:

```
eq2 = Hold[D[f[x], x]*g[x] + f[x] == 0];

ReleaseHold[eq2 /. sol]

(*  ==> {-g[x] - g[x] Derivative[1][g][x] == 0}  *)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works great for the problem, but for what I'm doing I can't hold `eq2` b/c I need to do some other calculations on it first. So I tried `ReleaseHold[Hold[eq2 /. f'[x] -> D[f[x], x]] /. sol]` which gives `{f[x] - g[x] g'[x]}`. But `ReleaseHold[Hold[eq2 /. f'[x] -> D[f[x], x]] /. sol] /. sol` does give the desired answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you plan to use derivatives, or solve for functions, you could use `DSolve` instead of `Solve`.

```
sol = DSolve[eq, f, x];
eq2 /. sol
```

> {-g[x] - g[x] Derivative[1][g][x] == 0}

If not, apart from avoiding the use of `x` overall, you could do something like this

```
parseRule = (f_[x_] -> sth_) :> (f -> (Evaluate[sth /. x -> #] &));

sol = Solve[eq, f[x]]

eq2 /. (sol /. parseRule)
```

> {-g[x] - g[x] Derivative[1][g][x] == 0}

I have the feeling there are better options. We'll see

Answer (score 3):

An approach that may in the long run help avoid confusion in your calculation is to use a different name for the function that is the solution to the equation `eq = f[x] + g[x] == 0`.

What I mean is this:

```
fSolved[x_] = f[x] /. First@Solve[eq, f[x]]

eq2 = fSolved'[x]*g[x] + fSolved[x] == 0

(* ==> {-g[x] - g[x] Derivative[1][g][x]} == 0 *)
```

So here I chose the name `fSolved` for the actual solution with which I want to work later.

This is mathematically more sane, I think, because `Solve` for `eq` could in principle give you *several* possible solutions in the form of a list of rules `f[x] -> ...`, and then you'd have to give each solution different names anyway if you want to keep working with both of them. As an example, consider

```
eq = f[x]^2 - g[x] == 0
```

Then by using `First` above we select the negative square root, and we could use a different name for the positive square root (`Last@Solve...`).

Comment: +1, definately more healthy. Any reason why you use `:=Evaluate` instead of plain `=` ? Syntax coloring?

Comment: @Rojo Yes - just to make sure we can also use `fSolved[y]` in `eq2` (i.e., be independent of the name `x` for the variable) if we feel like it...

Comment: I meant `fSolved[x_]:=Evaluate[...]` instead of `fSolved[x_]=...`

Comment: @Rojo Oh I see, yes in this case that's the same thing. I don't remember now why I thought it's better...

Comment: @Rojo Thanks for curing one of my bad habits - I removed the unnecessary `Evaluate`.

Comment: I guess it has the pro of being more noticeable, but the con of not having the correct syntax coloring that might lead to errors, such as `x=8;f[x_]=x;f[9]` giving 8. Matter of taste