# Why doesn't replace and evaluate?

Tags: debugging

The small example shows `ReplaceAll` doesn't replace and `Evaluate` doesn't evaluate.

```
Evaluate[h'[x] h''[x] /. h[x] -> c x^2]
```

it gives an unevaluated result.

```
(*Derivative[1][h][x] (h^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]*)
```

Comment: Try `h'[x] // FullForm` and you'll see why

Comment: see [replace-rule-with-function-derivatives-dont-evaluate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40189/replace-rule-with-function-derivatives-dont-evaluate) and [replace-function-and-its-derivatives-found-with-solve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6089/replace-function-and-its-derivatives-found-with-solve)

Comment: @ Nasser, @ Dr. belisarius, now, I got it. Do I need to delete the post?