# Replace a derivative within partial derivatives

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement

Suppose:

```
f = a + b g[x, y]
h = D[f, {x, 2}, {y, 1}]
(*Out:= b g^(2,1)[x,y]*)
```

1. In the function $h=b\frac{\partial^3g}{\partial x^2\partial y}$ I want to replace $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$ by $c\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ to obtain $h=bc\frac{\partial^3u}{\partial x^2\partial t}$.
2. In the function $h=b\frac{\partial^3g}{\partial x^2\partial y}$ I want to replace $\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}$ by $c\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ to obtain $h=bc\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y\partial t}$.

After looking at the `Fullform` of partial derivatives this seems like a hopeless task. I have also read this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6089/replace-function-and-its-derivatives-found-with-solve) but it hasn't  helped. Any suggestions and help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear@Derivative
Derivative[n_, 1][g][x, y] := c D[u[x, t], {x, n}, t]
h
Clear@Derivative
Derivative[2, n_][g][x, y] := c D[u[y, t], t, {y, n}]
h
```

You can use [`` Internal`InheritedBlock ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25769/1871) to avoid clearing `Derivative` again and again:

```
Clear@Derivative

Internal`InheritedBlock[{Derivative},
 Derivative[n_, 1][g][x, y] := c D[u[x, t], {x, n}, t]; h]

Internal`InheritedBlock[{Derivative},
 Derivative[2, n_][g][x, y] := c D[u[y, t], t, {y, n}]; h]
```

Comment: +1 Nice. What does Clear@Derivative exactly do here?

Comment: @Deep Otherwise the rule we created via `Derivative[2, n_][g][x, y] := c D[u[y, t], t, {y, n}]` etc. will remain. Try removing `Clear@Derivative` and execute `SubValues@Derivative` and you'll know what I mean.